# Display rating in html

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a project in django, where I have created a toplist based on the rating given in the reviews. Is there a way I can get the rating of the films showed in the html?

**from models.py**

```
class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title_short = models.CharField(max_length=17, default=None, null=True)
    plot = models.TextField()
    poster = models.ImageField(default="default.png", upload_to="posters")
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Review(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reviewed_film = models.ForeignKey(Film, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)]
    )

    def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return f"{self.reviewed_film.title} reviewed by {self.writer.username}"
```

**from toplist.html**

```
{% extends "board/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Toplist</h1>
  {% for film in films %}
    <div class="col s12 m7">
      <h2 class="header"></h2>
      <div class="card horizontal">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="/media/{{film.poster}}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-stacked">
          <div class="card-content">
            <h5>{{forloop.counter}}. {{film.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{}}/5.0</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Read more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague. Currently the answer is "Yes there are ways" - what is the exact issue you have?

Comment: I don´t know how to do it... :)

Comment: That doesn´t work, cause rating is under Review and not under Film in models.py I think

Comment: Shouldn't the relation be something like `Film.reviews.rating` because of the line in Review: `models.ForeignKey(Film, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`? I could be wrong here though.

Comment: But you mean "How do I go about to fill the film rating in my HTML using the Film class as input. I have tried this, this and this, but it gave error "error...."

Comment: That´s right @mplungjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `annotate` in your queryset. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

queryset = Film.objects.annotate(total_rating=Avg('reviews_rating'))
```

and then in your html file

```
{% for film in films %}

    <img src="/media/{{ film.poster }}">
    {{ forloop.counter }}. {{ film.title }}
    {{ film.total_rating }}/5.0

{% endfor %}
```

The [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) has more details.

Comment: What I had to do was like this: 

```
Film.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('reviews__rating'), total_rating=Round(Avg('reviews__rating'))).order_by('-avg_rating')[:10]
```
I also added a class Round(Func), to get the number of decimals I wanted.